# Missing dependencies MySQL Port

Tags: php, mysql

10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running 
10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped 
10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:55:39 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums

Comment: please elaborate more like how it happened and what is your system configuration running xam pp or installed the mysql server indpendently

Comment: Have you specified a different post in my.conf? Open my.conf and make sure what port you and and that windows isn't blocking that port. Also can you paste whats showing up in event viewer?

Comment: Turn off skype and check then. Skype uses same port as XAMPP mysql